# EaselJS filters not showing up downloaded examples

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, createjs, easeljs, colormatrixfilter

I'm having the strangest problem trying to develop with FF.
I've recently downloaded EaselJS and can open all the examples in Edge without any problems. 
The same would have been with Firefox except it doesn't seem to want to run any filters examples. Locally that is. From my hard disk. 
If I hit the same example online ( on the hosted author's page ) the filters seem to work fine. 
The same seems to be happening with the Chrome browser. 
Filter examples don't run locally but work fine on the author's page.

I was just wondering what I could be missing on.

Comment: So maybe I should stick to testing my pages either online somewhere or off a development server? Exclusively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters *may* work in local environments depending on the browser/system settings. Typically browsers won't be able to cache, because it requires pixel access, and on local systems this is usually disallowed, as it is treated similar to cross-domain images.

I recommend using a simple local server. You can run something like MAMP or XAMPP, or use an IDE with local testing servers. There are lots of options.

Comment: Thank you, I shall try. I now realise that Firefox is giving me a very clear "SecurityError: The operation is insecure.". This when I open from my local drive.

Comment: Yes. I can browse the filters examples in FF over a local testing server. I'm using plain IIS Express. The same applies with the Chrome browser. Success.

Answer (score 0):

So I think this has to do with browser security models. 
Both Firefox and Chrome have more strict guidelines it seems?